# how to generate RGBcolor in RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9) format

Tags: python, html, ms-word, rgb, python-docx

I am working with python docx and here I am stuck.

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run()
font = run.font
from docx.shared import RGBColor
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9)
```

This generate RGB(66, 36, 233) when viewed from microsoft word.

how can I get RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9) type color given RGB(66, 36, 233) format ?

Comment: Question still remains but using `font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 000, 000)` works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three parameters to RGBColor are just integers, so:

```
RGBColor(66, 36, 233)
```

Produces the same results as:

```
RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9)
```

The `0x` prefix is just a way of telling Python that what follows is to be interpreted as a base-16 number. It doesn't have to do with python-docx per se; any way you get an integer between 0 and 255 into those three positions will work fine.